# Selecting a set of values (with multiple tags) from a large pool by matching a common set of tags

Tags: c#, search, tags, filtering, inverted-index

I'm working on a game and need an efficient way to select a subset of records from a large set using a collection of tags.

There is a 3k+ collection of sounds and each one of those sounds is tagged with a number of simple tags. Collection is loaded once on startup and does not change at runtime, however, it is likely to change for each new build.

At runtime I need to react to certain events occurring in the game. This means I'll need to retrieve a sound that best suits the event's impact on the game world by using a set of tags that describe said event. Filter tags may have inclusion and exclusion tags.

This isn't a big issue and can be solved using relatively simple Linq. But my concern is that this code would be running inside a game loop. There could be any number of events occurring in a single frame so fastest possible search / fetch time for a sound is critical to avoid serious frame drops during "event heavy" moments in gameplay.

I don't expect to be doing this every single frame, but it's very likely that more than one event will occur during a single frame.

Now here is what the collection of sounds looks like :

```
audio-human-fall-01 <fall, impact, fatal>
audio-human-fall-02 <fall, floor, gear, impact>
audio-human-fall-03 <floor, fall, impact>
audio-human-fall-04 <fall, voiceover, fatal>
audio-human-fall-05 <fall, impact, floor, voiceover>
...
```

So, during the game my character falls and I have determined that the fall will not be fatal and the character will land on a floor.

I compose a tag set that looks like this :

```
<fall, floor, impact, -voiceover>
```

With a filter like this I expect to fetch the following sounds :

```
audio-human-fall-02 <fall, floor, impact, gear>
audio-human-fall-03 <floor, fall, impact>
```

I haven't begun implementing the selection algorithm as I'm still thinking of how to approach this problem. So far I was thinking of doing something like this :

- Iterate the original collection of sounds and build a
  `Dictionary<int, AudioClip>` where the key is a hash of a tag;
- When I need a sound that matches a set of tags I'll look up all KVPs from the dictionary that have the tag hashes I want;
- Once that is done I'll end up with a set of lists that can be unioned and then grouped;
- Groups with highest count are the AudioClips that best match the filter;
- Exclusions aren't a problem since unnecessary tags are never selected from the Dictionary;

Basically I'm wondering if this approach is any good to begin with and if not what would be a better solution to this problem. Any suggestions or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

PS : A theoretical / pseudo code solution would be just fine, not looking for anyone to do the work for me. Just need some guidance :D

**EDIT 1 :**

I found a few interesting articles on the subject and it seems the best way to go about this problem is to use an `InvertedIndex`. 
However, there is still the issue of fetch speed as the `InvertedIndex` will require a union operation on the result sets. This may cause problems and heavy frame drops.

Following a suggestion from a colleague of mine I'll try to implement something a bit different first. If that does work I'll give the `InvertedIndex` approach a try.

So, the idea is to create a `Dictionary` (at start up) that will contain references to the sounds in my collection. Each sound will be keyed by a sorted tag hash key for every combination of tags a given sound can have.

For a sound with these tags :

```
audio-human-fall-02 <fall, floor, impact>
```

I'll end up with a dictionary that will have something like :

```
<fall, floor, impact> audio-human-fall-02
<floor, fall, impact> audio-human-fall-02
<floor, impact, fall> audio-human-fall-02
<floor, impact, fall> audio-human-fall-02
<impact, floor, fall> audio-human-fall-02
<impact, fall, floor> audio-human-fall-02
<impact, floor, fall> audio-human-fall-02
<floor, impact, fall> audio-human-fall-02
<floor, fall, impact> audio-human-fall-02
etc...
```

Pro : Retrieval of a perfectly matched sound is instantaneous.

Con : Serious start up overhead and a relatively large dictionary for lookups.

Thanks,
- Alex